# List of coordinates to matrix of distances

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, distance

I've got a list of 8 coordinates stored as list of lists:

```
coordinates = [[47.2486, -1.54806],
               [43.5656, 1.47417],
               [48.3592, -4.57],
               [48.1439, 17.1097],
               [39.6275, 140.198],
               [30.0458, 31.2625],
               [38.9371, -77.0869],
               [33.9, 35.4823]]
```

With the following script, I seek to output a matrix of coordinates:

```
import numpy
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

coordinates_array = numpy.array(coordinates)
dist_array = pdist(coordinates_array)

dist_matrix = numpy.reshape(dist_array, newshape=(len(coordinates), len(coordinates)))
```

However, I get an `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the scipy documentation, use `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` to convert the condensed distance matrix returned by `pdist` to a square distance matrix,

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform 

dist_matrix = squareform(dist_array)
```